# Accessing every textview within gridview and setting colour to white

Tags: java, android

Sorry if this is a weird question, I just really don't understand how to get this working.
basically, I want a behavior so that when you click one of my gridview items, it highlights red,  This works fine, but I need it to only have 2 highlighted  letters at a time from the click method.

Outside this method is

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    //selection.setText(Words[position]);
}
```

This is inside my method which gets fired

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+arg2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    ((TextView) arg1).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                ((TextView) arg1).setTextSize(9);
    counter++;
    if(counter == 2)
    {
        //this needs to select everything in the gridview and set to white
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I would go about it ( if it's even possible)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it.

```
                if(counter == 3)
                {
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    // do the check if its a word or not

                    counter = 0;

            }
```

works like a charm